# Out of Bounds Access to CUDA shared memory

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I'm having problems with shared memory allocation within a kernel where I keep getting out of bounds errors. From my understanding each thread can be used to partially load data into the first shared block called `private_atom`, and within the for loop, on each iteration I'm loading the next consecutive block into a different shared memory in order to compute the spatial distance from my thread to all the threads in the next consecutive blocks, then I compute the distance between the thread and all other threads within the local block.

Since my error is regarding out of bounds issues I suspect my issue is with how I am copying memory into shared memory.

```
pdh_priv(bucket * histogram,atom * list, double width, int size, int BlockSize)
{
    int t = threadIdx.x;
    int b = blockIdx.x;
    unsigned int reg = t + b * blockDim.x;

    extern __shared__ atom private_atom[];

    if(t < BlockSize)   
        private_atom[t] = list[t];
    __syncthreads();


    for(int i = b + 1; i < size/BlockSize; ++i)
    {
        extern __shared__ atom localBlock[];
    
        unsigned int tempIdx = t + i *blockDim.x;
        localBlock[tempIdx] = list[tempIdx];
        __syncthreads();
        for(int j = 0; j < BlockSize;++j)
        {
            double distance = p2p_distance(private_atom[t], localBlock[j]);
            int pos = (int) (distance/width);
            atomicAdd(&histogram[pos].d_cnt,1);
        }
    
    }

    for(int i = t+1;i < BlockSize;++i)
    {
        double distance = p2p_distance(list,t,i);
        int pos = (int) (distance/width);
        atomicAdd( &histogram[pos].d_cnt,1);
    } 
}
```

I am launching the kernel with this call

```
pdh_priv <<<ceil(PDH_acnt/BlockSize),BlockSize,BlockSize*sizeof(atom) >>>(dev_Histo, dev_atomL,PDH_res,PDH_acnt,BlockSize);
```

Comment: `private_atom` and `localBlock` point at the same location. so the distance will always be 0. You don't even provide enough shared memory for two `atom`s per thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

the line:

```
localBlock[thempIdx] = list[tempIdx]
```

is trying to access an out of bounds location when it should only be writing to the thread location like so:

```
localBLock[thhreadIdx.x] = list[tempIdx];
```

Comment: Please either correct, reformat, and accept your answer or delete it so the question will fall off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag